# Error message when using imported library

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to use the validate_email library, more specifically in the verify and check_mx features.
Yesterday I installed the validate_email and Py3DNS libraries, and started to code - and I got outputs for line such as:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid2 = validate_email('example@example.com',check_mx=True)
```

Today when I wanted to continue my work, for the same line I get the following error:

```
Exception: For check the mx records or check if the email exists you must have installed pyDNS python package
```

Obviously the package is installed - when I ran the install line again I get:
Requirement already satisfied: Py3DNS in c:\users\owner\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.2.1)

Same issue with the 'verify' argument when set to true- same error.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using in in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Ops - yes, I'm on anaconda with jupyter notebook.

Comment: does the package appear in the output of `conda list` ?

Answer (score 0):

To possibilities for me:

Either you did not open the right enviornment, where you installed the packages:
[image]

or you should need to also import the other library:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
import py3dns
```

Comment: I don't think it either of those -
I only use the notebook for now (never opened any other environment).
I tried to import it as suggested - getting an error of:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Py3DNS'

Comment: change it to lower letters: py3dns

Comment: No, I wish it was that simple, also didn't help:/